# Error on sidebar's checkout button URL with IWD OPC extension

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, geturl

I have installed the IWD One Page Checkout extension on Magento 1.7.0.2, default theme.
The url in the **sidebar checkout button URL** isn't correct: it send to the default magento checkout ("../checkout/onepage").
Instead, the **"top link" checkout link** and the **"checkout" button** in the "cart" page works fine (sends to "../onepage"): the layout file "iwd_opc.xml" overwrite the checkout cart link.
Maybe I need something like this also for the sidebar's checkout button?

ps: changing template/sidebar.phtml from

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>"    class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"<span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>

to

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->__('../onepage') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
```

It resolve the problem, but it's not an elegant solution...

thanks (I accept every suggestion..)

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stackexchange. I can't see any difference between these two strings? Check the strings, hopefully you get an answer! Beside of this, is the question about a third party extension and therefore this is the wrong place for this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension

Comment: sorry, the code of the original sidebar.phtml is <?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually using `<?php echo $this->__('../onepage') ?>` means you are using the translate method to create an URL. It's advised to use the Magento `getUrl` method like so:

`<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/index'); ?>`

I'm not too familiar with the extension but basically you should be able to get the correct URL using this method.

`<?php echo Mage::getUrl('[extension name]/[controllername]/[method name]'); ?>`

Where **extension** name will be *opc* and method and controller name probably something like *index*

Comment: I used '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('onepage/index'); ?>' and it works!!!